# Javascript Request--> Get API from https

Tags: javascript, python, https, request

I need to connect a database to a website and I have already done this with python for my application, but it seems hooking it up with javascript is going to be much harder.

Both headers and parameters are filled with key:value pairs with the information necessary.

Here is my code that I have for python:

```py
response = requests.get("https://websiteAPI", headers=headers, params=parameters)
```

I need to be able to change the headers, as that is where I have my password for the api stored and also change the parameters so that I am able to get what I need.

Currently I am using the request library from javascript and have this, but I am still getting numerous errors from this.

```js
var response = new request.Request("https://websiteAPI", {headers: headers} );
```

Is there something that I am missing to make the hookup to javascript as easy as it is in python?

Comment: Is there something that I am missing to make the hookup to javascript as easy as it is in python? YUP; I'd be just copying the fetch result from developer console (under networking).

Comment: @blanknamefornow could you explain this a bit more? EDIT: I got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was using fetch with documentation found here.

```js
var fetchUrl = require('fetch').fetchUrl

var response = fetchUrl("https://websiteAPI/?limit = 25&offset = 0", {headers:{"code" : "code"}}, function(error, meta, body){
    console.log(body.toString());
});
```

Add any parameters after the ? in the URL and seperate them by &, then add information needed for headers in the headers section. Still a bit more messy than python but it works.